# Как определить разрядность операционной системы средствами .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, windows-7

Имеется C# приложение для Win 7, во время исполнения которого требуется определить, запущено оно на 32 или 64 bit'ой версии ОС. Возможно ли это сделать с помощью .NET или же необходимо использовать "обходные" пути?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336633/how-to-detect-windows-64-bit-platform-with-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выяснить разрядность ОС (32 или 64 bit) непосредственно средствами .NET невозможно,  однако существуют способы с использованием WinAPI:

1. С помощью функции **IsWow64Process**

   ```
   public static string GetOSBit() {
       bool is64bit = Is64Bit();
       if (is64bit)
           return "x64";
       else
           return "x32";
       }

   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
   public static extern bool IsWow64Process([In] IntPtr hProcess, [Out] out bool lpSystemInfo);

   public static bool Is64Bit()
   {
       bool retVal;
       IsWow64Process(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle, out retVal);
       return retVal;
   }
   ```
2. С помощью размера типа **IntPtr**

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
   class OSBitChecker
   {
       static bool Is64Bit
       {
           get { return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)) == 8; }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: >непосредственно средствами .NET невозможно

а мой ответ вы читали?

Comment: Второй способ некорректен:

> IntPtr.Size won't return the correct value if running in 32-bit .NET Framework 2.0 on 64-bit Windows (it would return 32-bit).

Comment: Да 2-ой вариант кривоват, а вот 1-ый работает от души)

Comment: Не вполне понятно как первый способ может работать: IsWow64Process вернёт false если у вас 64х-битное приложение. Надо комбинировать оба способа.

Answer (score 6):

- **[Environment Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.aspx)**
- [Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitoperatingsystem.aspx)
- [Environment.Is64BitProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.is64bitprocess.aspx)

Comment: Не портабельно для `.NET < 4.0`

Comment: фейл, однако

Answer (score 2):

Вот :D

```
if(Directory.Exists(@"C:\Windows\SysWOW64") == true)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Ваш виндовс, безусловно 64 разрядный.");
}
else 
{
  Console.WriteLine("Не, разрядность вашего виндовс, такая же, сколько у человека зубов =(");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Шутка конечно, но катит) Если что, можно поменять на

```
 if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)") == true)
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Ваш виндовс, безусловно 64 разрядный.");
 }
 else 
 {
    Console.WriteLine("Не, разрядность вашего виндовс, такая же, сколько у человека зубов =(");
 }
 Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: в натуре четко!1!!

Comment: Пошутить нельзя, сразу заминусовали)

Comment: Евгений Ваганыч, не переживайте так :)

Comment: Зато этот способ работает на всех языках, которые могут работать с файлами. Но ведь не все имеют встроенные функции и возможность подключения WinAPI.

Comment: Ещё нужно учесть, что %SYSTEMROOT% может быть не C:\Windows\
Но за шутку ловите "+", а то тут народ совсем заминусовал, написано же заранее, что шутка :)

Comment: Да, это веское обоснование того, что стоит реализовывать метод `Is64BitOperatingSystem` так, чтобы: 

- На каждый его вызов делалось обращение к диску.
- Он [фейлился][1] в случае, если у пользователя нет прав для обращения к `SysWOW64`.
- Он фейлился в случае, если юзер на 32 битной системе создал папку `SysWOW64` или `Program Files (x86)`.

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.directory.exists

Comment: Mikola, видимо юмор очень жесткий :)

Comment: Интересно послушать про фокусы с кешированием ОЗУ на ЖД :)

Comment: >Directory.Exists(@"C:\Program Files (x86)")

 А если её пользователь сам создал? Понятно, что вряд ли, но этот метод нестабильный.

 Кстати, я заметил, что при установке программ на x64 Windows папка по умолчанию выглядит, как "C:\Program Files (x86)", а на 32-битной - C:\Program Files. Наверняка инсталляторы используют какую-то функцию для получения этих путей. Значит, можно и самому её использовать и без всяких обращений к диску узнать разрядность.

Answer (score -2):

Вот хороший [пост](http://sources.ru/csharp/OSVersionInfo.html) по этому поводу:

Comment: А за что минус то?!?

Comment: @Чад, если не трудно, добавьте в ответ суть из поста. А то этот ответ на удаление поставлен.

Answer (score -2):

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem) Console.WriteLine("64Bit");
            else Console.WriteLine("32Bit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

```
bool is64bit = System.Environment.OSVersion.Major > 5;
```

Comment: Любая `Windows 7` является 64-битной?