# Узнать разрядность ОС Windows C++

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Здравствуйте, возник вопрос с тем, как узнать разрядность ОС Windows. Пробовал через препроцессинг, но выдает неправильные данные...

```
#ifdef WIN64
#define OS_BIT 64
#endif // !WIN64

#ifdef WIN32
#define OS_BIT 32
#endif // !WIN32
```

Может быть есть какой-нибудь другой способ?

Comment: Этими ifdef вы получите только target-разрядность программы (то есть для какой платформы она собирается). И, кстати, по-моему, это AMD64

Comment: Не хочу давить вопрос золотыми медалями :), поскольку я не уверен в полном дубле - там вопрос по C#... Но переписать на С - раз плюнуть... так что я просто озадачу других - вы не находите, что данный вопрос - дубль вот этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/127037/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-net

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
BOOL Is64BitWindows()
{
#if defined(_WIN64)
 return TRUE;  // Программа скомпилирована для x64
#elif defined(_WIN32)
 // Программа скомпилирована для x32, спрашиваем ОС
 BOOL f64 = FALSE;
 return IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f64) && f64;
#else
 return FALSE; // Программа скомпилирована для x16
#endif
}
```

Источник: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050201-00/?p=36553/

Comment: Есть мнение, что получать IsWow64Process нужно через GetProcAddress() и корректно обрабатывать ошибки. Эта функция есть далеко не всякой винде.

Comment: Осталось узнать у автора, собирается ли он запускать программу только на поддерживаемой винде, или нет...

Comment: Все также показывает, что у меня х32 система, хотя стоит х64

Answer (score 3):

Можно попытаться узнать путь к папке Wow64. На 32-битных системах этот вызов всегда возвращает `FALSE` и код ошибки будет `ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED`. Привилегированных прав для вызова не требуется, должна работать начиная с WindowsXP (на 10 работает точно).

```
bool Is64bitWindows(void) noexcept
{
    auto is_64_bit{true};
    if(FALSE == GetSystemWow64DirectoryW(nullptr, 0u))
    {
        auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};
        if(ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED == last_error)
        {
            is_64_bit = false;
        }
    }
    return(is_64_bit);
}
```