# Не работает IsWow64Process для вычисления битности ОС

Tags: c, winapi

возникла такая проблема: при компиляции возникает такая ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения].Перелазил все, но не понял в чем проблема.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool Is64BitWindows()
{
#if defined(_WIN64)
    return true;  // Программа скомпилирована для x64
#elif defined(_WIN32)
    // Программа скомпилирована для x32, спрашиваем ОС
    bool f64 = false;
    return IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &f64) && f64;
#else
    return false; // Программа скомпилирована для x16
#endif
}

int main() {
    printf("64 = %d", Is64BitWindows());
    return 0;
}
```

Оригинал кода:[Узнать разрядность ОС Windows C++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/747629/%D0%A3%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%9E%D0%A1-windows-c)

Answer (score 1):

Лучше использовать [пример кода с сайта Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wow64apiset/nf-wow64apiset-iswow64process). Уж они-то разбираются в WinAPI.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef BOOL (WINAPI *LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) (HANDLE, PBOOL);

LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS fnIsWow64Process;

BOOL IsWow64()
{
    BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;

    //IsWow64Process is not available on all supported versions of Windows.
    //Use GetModuleHandle to get a handle to the DLL that contains the function
    //and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the function if available.

    fnIsWow64Process = (LPFN_ISWOW64PROCESS) GetProcAddress(
        GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32")),"IsWow64Process");

    if(NULL != fnIsWow64Process)
    {
        if (!fnIsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(),&bIsWow64))
        {
            //handle error
        }
    }
    return bIsWow64;
}

int main( void )
{
    if(IsWow64())
        _tprintf(TEXT("The process is running under WOW64.\n"));
    else
        _tprintf(TEXT("The process is not running under WOW64.\n"));

    return 0;
}
```

А внимательное чтение комментария объяснит, почему не компилируется ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете типы `bool` и `BOOL`. Это разные вещи.

Если вы пользовались компилятором VC++, то должны были обратить внимание на предупреждение

> warning C4133: функция: несовместимые типы - из "bool *" в "PBOOL"

Вернитесь к коду по приведенной вами ссылке.